# web app is sharing the same memory storage

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, web

I working in a  app that i use to compute user details. But somehow, the values of a user alter that of another user.
Below is a fragment of the code

```
def Compute_UserScore(self, details, ques_no):
    try:
        if(HomePage.answer_.strip() == ""):
            self.response.write("""<script type = "text/javascript">
            alert("Dear User, You can not answer same answer twice.. Take test Again !");
            </script>""")
            self.redirect('/otherPages/subjectSelect.html')
        else:
            count = 0
            HomePage.ans_no = 0
            HomePage.unans_no = 0
            HomePage.correct_no = 0
            HomePage.wrong_no = 0
            HomePage.failed_ques = list()
            HomePage.answer_ = HomePage.answer_.strip()
            question_1 = HomePage.question_.split(" gcdc_split_format ")
            while (count != (ques_no)):
                user_answer = str(details[count]).strip().capitalize()
                real_answer = str(HomePage.answer_[count]).strip().capitalize()
                if (len(str(user_answer).strip()) == 1):
                    HomePage.ans_no = HomePage.ans_no + 1
                    if(user_answer.strip() == real_answer.strip()):
                        HomePage.correct_no = HomePage.correct_no + 1
                    else:
                        HomePage.wrong_no = HomePage.wrong_no + 1
                        HomePage.failed_ques.append(str("No. " + str(int((count + 1))) + "  " + str(question_1[count])))
                else:
                    HomePage.unans_no = HomePage.unans_no + 1
                count = count + 1
            HomePage.answer_ = ""
    except:
        self.redirect('/')
    return " "
```

and this is how my homepage looks like

```
class HomePage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    percentage = None
    subject_answered = None
    username_ = None
    email_ = None
    super_date = None
    answer_ = " "
    question_ = " "
    failed_ques = list()
    wrong_no = 0
    correct_no = 0
    ans_no = 0
    unans_no = 0
```

The problem is, when a user A, take a test, He sees the result of another user B.
Read about Using instance variable, but still have not figure ouut how to make it work

Comment: Why are you setting class variables in an instance method?

Comment: The code above is the problem. That is why i am asking for a why out. a link to a page that ll help or better stil, a sample code. thanks @Wooble

Comment: What is wrong with the answers you got when you previously asked this exact question?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, yea, i asked that also. But i have been trying to make it work, but still no progress

Comment: Exactelly  what @DanielRoseman said. You need a system to differenciate between users. Start Check how to use the users service https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingusers  in order to start building a good app and not that little monster you are creating.

Comment: already have google sign-in enabled. Users access the app with their google account.

Comment: Honestly your problem is simple: you are lacking some basic understanding of programming web applications. I recommend reading some books/doing some courses. It's dishonest to try to use this community as your personal tutor without putting in the effort required to get the basics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is simple: Stop setting class variables in web development! :)
Web requests are stateless, it's mean you never know what's happen between requests - between setting class variable and redirect.

Use database to store temporary data with user login/name (or use hashing/random for security) or send values by parameters (hidden or after '?') to other html page.
Using database is better, if you don't want this then send values (hidden in html) over http. Here is one version of solution (without database):

1.Use normal html form and write handler for this form - question page.

2.In handler write get method like this:

```
def post(self, some_parameters):
   ...
   self.render('homepage.html', {'ans_no': ans_no,\
                                'uans_no': uans_no ...})
```

3.homepage.html have to be template for showing results

Comment: Of course this is post method - my mistake :)